# How do I center one image over another in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a clock component with a face image and a needle centered on the clock in React Native. 
 does not allow embedding other Images.
I found a few posts for centering text over images but cannot find any way do center Image over images.

Edit:
I'm trying to find a way that avoids giving absolute position so the component can be dynamically sized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want to show one image over other image. With one as a Parent image and other as a child image without using absolute postion.
For this you can use **ImageBackground** Component provided by react-native and by setting its height and width with percentage value.

Below is the example :

**Parent Image** : Clock.png is an **ImageBackground** Component

**Child Image** : Needle.png is an **Image** Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native'

export default class ImageView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 0.25,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'red'
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 26 }}>I am Header</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            // backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'red'
          }}
        >
          <ImageBackground
            source={require('@assets/Clock.png')}
            style={{
              height: '60%',
              width: '100%'
            }}
            resizeMode="contain"
          >
            <Image
              style={{
                marginTop: '4.5%',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                height: '30%',
                width: '100%'
              }}
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={require('@assets/Needle.png')}
            />
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[image: Clock]

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same as you would handle this in regular old html,css.

Use `position:absolute` then align the items so that they match how you expect.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way that avoid having to give absolute values as I want the component to dymanically size.